# Call previous value input into the textbox in Ms Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table(table Income) with 8 fields for recording Income and Expense.

1. No: AutoNumber
2. PL: Income/Expense
3. Date
4. Staff_ID
5. Customer_ID
6. Payment_Type: Cash, Credit,...
7. Service
8. Amount

I create a form with a subform for data input.
cmb_pl, cmb_date,  cmb_staffid, cmb_custid, cmb_type, cmb_service, txt_amount
Income  03-Dec-20  1            2           Credit    hair_cut     $15

After click button Add then this record will run into subform.
Next I input second record which few differences from first record.

cmb_pl, cmb_date,  cmb_staffid, cmb_custid, cmb_type, cmb_service, txt_amount
Income  03-Dec-20  1            2           Credit    nail_fix     $18

In this case, if I lazy to reinput the data then I just only double click on those fields then data from previous record (first record) will come itself. And for those which not double click then I can insert the value from the combo or textbox.

So, what is your direction for making this works?

Million thanks for your wonderful support!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA in each control's BeforeUpdate or AfterUpdate event to set its DefaultValue property. Value will carry forward to each new record until user inputs a different value. No double click required.

`Me.YourControlName.DefaultValue = """" & Me.YourControlName.Value & """"`

This syntax is valid for Text, Number, DateTime and Boolean Datatypes.